# Adding variables to dictionary, same format

Tags: python

I want to make the variables that a user inputs, add to the dictionary. But I want it to be added the way that it currently looks:

```
bookLogger = [
    {'BookName': 'Noise', 'Author': 'Daniel Kahneman', 'Process': 'Reading' },
    {'BookName': 'Hunting Party', 'Author': 'Lucy Foley', 'Process': 'Reading'},
    {'BookName': 'Superintelligence', 'Author': 'Nick Bostrom', 'Process': 'Not Reading'}
]
```

The code that I have tried

```
def AddingBooks():

    #User inputs what they want to add tot he library
    BName = input("Please enter the book name: ")
    BAuthor = input("Enter the books Author: ")
    BProcess = input("Are you reading, not reading or haven't started ")

    #Want to add this to the bookLogger but in the same format that the
    #bookLogger dictionary is in
    bookLogger['BookName'] = BName
    bookLogger['Author'] = BAuthor
    bookLogger['Process'] = BProcess
```

The error that comes up is `list indices must be integers or slices, not str` for the `bookLogger['BookName'] = BName` line.

NOTE:
Not sure how to change it + not sure if that will add it to the `bookLogger` the way I want it to.

Comment: `bookLogger` is a list (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) and you are assuming that it is a dictionary (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Comment: So rather than trying to add it like its a dictionary, I should add to my list a dictionary with the inputs?

Comment: You could create a dictionary from the inputs and then `append()` *that* to the `bookLogger` **list** (it's a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself).

Answer (score 1):

`bookLogger`  is a list that has a dictionary. So You have to push or `append` the dictionary to the list.

```
bookLogger = [
{'BookName': 'Noise', 'Author': 'Daniel Kahneman', 'Process': 'Reading' },
{'BookName': 'Hunting Party', 'Author': 'Lucy Foley', 'Process': 'Reading'},
{'BookName': 'Superintelligence', 'Author': 'Nick Bostrom', 'Process': 'Not Reading'}
]

def AddingBooks():
    #User inputs what they want to add tot he library
    BName = input("Please enter the book name: ")
    BAuthor = input("Enter the books Author: ")
    BProcess = input("Are you reading, not reading or haven't started ")
    
    #Want to add this to the bookLogger but in the same format that the bookLogger 
    bookLogger.append({"BookName": BName, "Author": BAuthor, "Process": BProcess})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to using string as a list index. i.e `bookLogger['BookName']`. `'BookName'` is an index. But you cannot use such string values for the list.
If your logger is

```py
bookLogger = [
    {'BookName': 'Noise', 'Author': 'Daniel Kahneman', 'Process': 'Reading' },
    {'BookName': 'Hunting Party', 'Author': 'Lucy Foley', 'Process': 'Reading'},
    {'BookName': 'Superintelligence', 'Author': 'Nick Bostrom', 'Process': 'Not Reading'}
]
```

You can write a function this way.

```py
def AddingBooks():

    # User inputs what they want to add tot he library
    BName = input("Please enter the book name: ")
    BAuthor = input("Enter the books Author: ")
    BProcess = input("Are you reading, not reading or haven't started ")

    # Want to add this to the bookLogger but in the same format that 
      the
    # bookLogger dictionary is in

    #first create a dictionary
    log = {'BookName': BName,
           'Author': BAuthor,
           "Process": BProcess}

    #bookLogger is a list so you have to append individual log to it
    bookLogger.append(log)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).